# Python: Groupby with conditions in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below.

I need to do groupby(country and product) and **Value** column should contain **count(id) where status is closed** and I need to return remaining columns. Expected output format as below.

```
Sample input

id        status    ticket_time           product      country     last_load_time       metric_id   name
1260057   open      2021-10-04 01:20:00   Broadband    Grenada     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
2998178   open      2021-10-02 00:00:00   Fixed Voice  Bahamas     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
3762949   closed    2021-10-01 00:00:00   Fixed Voice  St Lucia    2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
3766608   closed    2021-10-04 00:00:00   Broadband    St Lucia    2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
3767125   closed    2021-10-04 00:00:00   TV           Antigua     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
6050009   closed    2021-10-01 00:00:00   TV           Jamaica     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
6050608   open      2021-10-01 00:00:00   Broadband    Jamaica     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
6050972   open      2021-10-01 00:00:00   Broadband    Jamaica     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
6052253   closed    2021-10-02 00:00:00   Broadband    Jamaica     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair
6053697   open      2021-10-03 00:00:00   Broadband    Jamaica     2021-12-09 09:57:27  MTR013      repair  

**EXPECTED OUTPUT FORMAT** SAMPLE

country  product    load_time          metric_id     name          ticket_time        Value(count(id)with status closed)
Antigua   TV      2021-12-09 09:57:27   MTR013     pending_repair   2021-10-01         1
....      ...     ....                  ...        ...              ...                2
```

**I tried the below code:**

```
df = new_df[new_df['status'] == 'closed'].groupby(['country', 'product']).agg(Value = pd.NamedAgg(column='id', aggfunc="size"))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But it is returning only three columns **country, product and value**.

I need the remaining columns which I mentioned in the above EXPECTED OUTPUT FORMAT.
Also ,I tried

```
df1 = new_df[new_df['status'] == 'closed']
df1['Value'] = df1.groupby(['country', 'product'])['status'].transform('size')

df = df1.drop_duplicates(['country', 'product']).drop('status', axis=1)
```

Output

```
id    ticket_time    product    country     load_time          metric_id    name        Value
3762949 2021-10-01  Fixed Voice St Lucia    2021-12-09 09:57:27 MTR013  pending_repair  23
3766608 2021-10-04  Broadband   St Lucia    2021-12-09 09:57:27 MTR013  pending_repair  87
```

Second logic with transform returning id column which I don't want. Value column is based on count(id) where status is closed. I tried the above two methods but not able to get the expected output. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group-by, typically, you're aggregating the data according to some category, so you won't keep all of the individual records, but will only be left with the columns that you've grouped-by and the column of aggregated data (a count, a mean, etc). However, the transform function will do what you want it to. I think this is what you were looking for based on your EXPECTED OUTPUT.

```
df_closed = df[df['status']=='closed']  # Filters data

df_closed = df_closed.reindex()  # Resets index

df_closed['count_closed'] = df_closed.groupby('country')['status'].transform(len)
```